# When a module is imported into a Ruby class, is it similar to composition?

Tags: ruby, composition

When you import a module into a class, is it similar in nature to OOP composition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's more like multiple inheritance, but not completely the same. Modules can be used to mix-in functionality, so you don't have to rewrite the same code for multiple classes.  Composition is where objects hold references to other objects.

Answer (score 0):

I may be getting my design pattern terminology mixed up, but have you looked at `def_delegator` and `def_delegators` from Ruby's standard library `forwardable`?